# Container DNS resolutions works only after restarting dnsmasq

Tags: domain-name-system, docker, internal-dns, dnsmasq

**[Update] add software versions**

I have a home server which runs docker and DNS/DHCP for my home network. It's all working quite nicely except for one thing: Containers can't do DNS resolution after reboot. Once I restart dnsmasq it starts working immediately.

if I look into journalctl I see this message: `Oct 29 23:56:15 hub.mi.casa dnsmasq[425]: Ignoring query from non-local network`

I *think* that docker creates some network interfaces which dnsmasq does not pick up after being started, although the dnsmasq docs clearly state ...

> On systems which support it, dnsmasq binds the wildcard address, even when it is listening on only some interfaces. It then discards requests that it shouldn't reply to. This has the advantage of working even when interfaces come and go and change address. [...] (from: `--bind-interfaces`)

... so I guess this *should* work.

System config:

- Debian Bullseye (11.1)
- Docker v20.10.10 (Docker repos), no special settings (DOCKER_OPTS etc.)
- dnsmasq v2.85 (Debian repos)
- `systemd-resolved` active but `DNSStubListener=no` is set
- `systemd-networkd` handles the network (static IP address)

I can't figure out what to do here, does anybody have any ideas? I *did* find a [RedHat bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1184710) which describes pretty much exactly what I'm experiencing, it is supposed to be solved though.

I don't really want to start dnsmasq after docker, cause the system and my whole network works just fine without docker, but not without dnsmasq.

### Config files

**dnsmasq.conf**

```
# MAIN SETTINGS

port=53
domain-needed
expand-hosts
bogus-priv
no-resolv
no-hosts

server=127.0.0.1#8053

# DHCP CONFIGURATION

dhcp-range=192.168.1.150,192.168.1.200,12h
domain=mi.casa
local=/fritz.box/

# set dhcp options ("dnsmasq --help dhcp" for list)
dhcp-option=option:router,192.168.1.1
dhcp-option=option:dns-server,192.168.1.13
dhcp-option=option:domain-search,mi.casa

# static IP address assignments using DHCP (example)
dhcp-host=aa:cc:dd:ff:ee:33,hass.mi.casa,192.168.1.20

# static ip address entries (example)
address=/hub.mi.casa/192.168.1.13
```

**/etc/systemd/network/10-static.network**

```
[Match]
Name=en*

[Network]
Address=192.168.1.13/24
Gateway=192.168.1.1
DNS=192.168.1.13#8053 # that's a pi-hole running on the system
Domains=mi.casa
```

Answer (score 0):

holy moly, I found the solution here, in a barely-two-line comment from @mosvy under a [somewhat related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/470745). based on that I even have two solutions now.

goal seems to be to disable the restriction to serve only local networks. there seem to be two ways.

### solution 1

```
# dnsmasq.conf - add this - thanks @mosvy
except-interface=my_dummy_interface
```

yes, it is actually `my_dummy_interface`, it's a name that does not exist (you could also call it "smurfydurfy"). so dnsmasq binds *and answers* on all interfaces automatically, except on one ... that does never show up.

### solutions 2

```
# dnsmasq.conf - add this
listen-address=127.0.0.1,192.168.1.13
```

same thing apparently, it binds on those addresses and answers all requests regardless of origin.